# How to fill PDF form with specific font using pdfbox?

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I am trying to fill pdf form and I am able to fill it using the following approach through PDFBox library.

```
val pdf: PDDocument = PDDocument.load(file)
pdf.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true)
val docCatalog: PDDocumentCatalog = pdf.getDocumentCatalog
val acroForm: PDAcroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm

def populateFields(inputJson: String, targetPdfPath: String): Unit = {
    val valueMap: Array[Field] = gson.fromJson(inputJson, classOf[Array[Field]])
    valueMap.foreach((field) => {
      val pdField: PDField = acroForm.getField(field.name)

      if (pdField != null) {
        pdField.setValue(field.value)
      } else {
        println(s"No field with name ${field.name}")
      }
    })

    pdf.save(targetPdfPath)
    pdf.close()
  }
```

The only problem is, I don't see any option to set the font before filling the pdf. Can you help me here?

Comment: The font for the field is taking from the field definition. Why do you want to change it? To change it you need to a) add the font to the AcroForm default resources and b) change the default appearance string to use that font. For a simple sample take a look at `CreateSimpleForm.java` in `org.apache.pdfbox.examples.interactive.form`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by using these methods (note that you have to use PDFBox 1.8.15, not the newer 2.0).

```java
// Set the field with custom font.
private void setField(String name, String value, String fontSource) throws IOException {
    PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog;
    PDAcroForm acroForm;
    PDField field;
    COSDictionary dict;
    COSString defaultAppearance;
    docCatalog = pdfTemplate.getDocumentCatalog();
    acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
    field = acroForm.getField(name);
    dict = (field).getDictionary();
    defaultAppearance = (COSString) dict.getDictionaryObject(COSName.DA);

    if (defaultAppearance != null)
    {
        dict.setString(COSName.DA, "/" + fontName + " 10 Tf 0 g");
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Field1")) {
            dict.setString(COSName.DA, "/" + fontName + " 12 Tf 0 g");
        }
    }
    if (field instanceof PDTextbox)
    {
        field = new PDTextbox(acroForm, dict);
        (field).setValue(value);
    }
}

// Set the field with custom font.
private List<String> prepareFont(PDDocument _pdfDocument, List<PDFont> fonts) {
    PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = _pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();

    PDResources res = acroForm.getDefaultResources();
    if (res == null)
        res = new PDResources();

    List<String> fontNames = new ArrayList<>();
    for (PDFont font: fonts)
    {
        fontNames.add(res.addFont(font));
    }

    acroForm.setDefaultResources(res);
    return fontNames;
}

// Set the field with custom font.
private PDFont loadTrueTypeFont(PDDocument _pdfDocument, String resourceName) throws IOException
{
    return PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(_pdfDocument, new File(resourceName));
}
```

Now, you only have to source the method `setField` with the name of the field, the value you want to insert and a string which is the path to the TTF font you wanna use.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The current 1.8 version is 1.8.15. Previous ones have security issues. Please correct your answer (which is most probably good).

Comment: Thanks. For an example with 2.0, see the `CreateSimpleFormWithEmbeddedFont.java` example from the source code download.